# How to load a model in .json in three.js

Tags: webgl

I need to load a model "somemodel.json" into my "movie.js".Can someone tell me where i am going wrong.I followed the steps given [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/ObjectLoader).

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset=utf-8>
         <title>Test</title>
         <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ObjectLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="movie.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**movie.js**

```js
var camera;
var scene;
var renderer;
var loader;

frame();
animate();

function frame() {

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth /     window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 10;
camera.rotation.x = 0;

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load(
'somemodel.json',
function () {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3,32,32);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( object );
}
);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
render();
}

function animate() {
render();
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function render() {
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Or can your give an example with a sample model ?

When i run my file it raises an error in the console saying `not well-formed        male.json`

Answer (score 2):

The error `not well-formed        male.json` doesn't appear to have anything to do with the code you've posted. I don't see any references to a JSON file called `male.json`.

If this file is in your code somewhere, the error is telling you the problem. It is malformed. Paste the contents of the file into an online validation tool such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). It will tell you what is making it malformed.

Also, you're passing JSON into `ObjectLoader.load` but you don't do anything with the results. Instead try this:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load('somemodel.json', function (object) {
    scene.add(object);
});
```

Check out [the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader) for more information.